# ZF Boilerplate's zend version

Tags: zend-framework, version, zf-boilerplate

I had a quick question here.

I was wondering if anyone knew on which version of the Zend Framework, the ZF Boilerplate is running on.

I am planning on using it but so far I was working on the ZF 1.x and I wonder if there would be a difference...

Comment: FYI to others: http://zf-boilerplate.com/ .. I had to look it up.  Did you see the link, "Check out ZF-Boilerplate 2 EARLY ALPHA"? on the home page?  Suggests it is on version 1 now and would eventually support 2 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It runs both:

ZF1: https://github.com/michael-romer/zf-boilerplate (stable)

ZF2: https://github.com/michael-romer/zf-boilerplate/tree/v2 (not-stable)